# Tracing OpenTelemetry + String Boot + Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, open-telemetry

I try add tracing(not metrics) to spring boot application with kafka.
I read this [doc](https://opentelemetry.io/blog/2022/instrument-kafka-clients/#using-the-interceptors).
I add

```
    implementation("io.opentelemetry.instrumentation", "opentelemetry-kafka-clients-2.6", "+")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud" , "spring-cloud-starter-sleuth")
```

add property to my poducer

```
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: com.github.thake.kafka.avro4k.serializer.KafkaAvro4kSerializer
      client-id: "client-1"
      properties:
        interceptor:
          classes: io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.kafkaclients.v2_6.TracingProducerInterceptor
```

But i don't see any header in message. After 3 hour debuging i understend that opentelemetry intercepter don't undersend, that i need B3 propagator from spring-cloud-starter-sleuth. Now i see `NoopTextMapPropagator` which doesn't add any headers.
I try add some ather dependency from doc

```
    implementation("io.opentelemetry", "opentelemetry-sdk", "+")
    implementation("io.opentelemetry", "opentelemetry-sdk-extension-autoconfigure", "+")
```

But it's not work.
I expect that opentelemetry have some auto config for B3 propagator or some guide `how to` add it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to set up an `OpenTelemetry` instance before you use any of the OTel instrumentations. You can do that either completely [by hand](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/manual/#sdk-configuration), using the [SDK autoconfigure](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/tree/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure) module, or you can use the [javaagent](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/java/automatic/) and have it setup both the SDK and all the instrumentations automatically (if you use the agent you won't have to install any Kafka instrumentation yourself, the agent will do that for you).

Judging by the example you posted, you included the autoconfigure module in your app - you'll need to initialize it so that it builds an `OpenTelemetry` instance. For example, you could add the following bean:

```java
@Bean
OpenTelemetry openTelemetry() {
  return AutoConfiguredOpenTelemetrySdk.initialize().getOpenTelemetrySdk();
}
```

If you want to use the B3 propagator you can set the `otel.propagators`/`OTEL_PROPAGATORS` system property/env var to `b3` (also see [link](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/tree/main/sdk-extensions/autoconfigure#propagator)); the autoconfigure module will detect that and use the configured propagator.

Lastly, since you want to instrument the Kafka client, I recommend using both `kafka-clients-2.6` and `spring-kafka-2.7` instrumentation libraries. The `spring-kafka` instrumentation really improvers the consumer-side telemetry.
Here's an example on how to set it up: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/d7d629617aa942abfa689878ea8af85f2d8d507b/instrumentation/spring/spring-kafka-2.7/library/src/test/java/io/opentelemetry/instrumentation/spring/kafka/v2_7/SpringKafkaNoReceiveTelemetryTest.java#L38C1-L57